# Find & track max value in a multidimensial array

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2280764150
        [label] => Some Label A
        [pda] => 5.34
        [prt] => 67
        [kps] => 12436
        [xmv] =>  1.24
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2273499083
        [label] => Some Label B
        [pda] => 2.99
        [prt] => 97
        [kps] => 212436
        [xmv] =>  7.78
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2273045947
        [label] => Some Label C
        [pda] => 6.34
        [prt] => 157
        [kps] => 1436
        [xmv] =>  2.34
    )

)
```

What I would like to do is find out which array element has the max value for each of items `pda` `prt` `kps` and `xmv`. It's not so much I want to know what the max value is, but I want to know which one has the max elements for each. So `Some Label C` would be logged as having max `pda`, `Some Label B` having max value for `kps` and so on.

I could do this with a few loops, but was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why using few loops not an elegant solution?

Comment: It can be. I thought using `array_reduce` or something like that would be much tidier. Just looking for the best suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another one. I'm not sure if it's elegant, though.

```
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>2280764150,'label'=>'Some Label A','pda'=>5.34,'prt'=>67,'kps'=>12436,'xmv'=>1.24),
    array('id'=>2273499083,'label'=>'Some Label B','pda'=>2.99,'prt'=>97,'kps'=>212436,'xmv'=>7.78),
    array('id'=>2273045947,'label'=>'Some Label C','pda'=>6.34,'prt'=>157,'kps'=>1436,'xmv'=>2.34),
);

$max = array('pda'=>0,'prt'=>0,'kps'=>0);
foreach (array_keys($max) as $key) {
    array_walk($arr,'get_max',$key);
}

function get_max($inner_arr,$index,$key) {
    global $max;
    if ($inner_arr[$key] > $max[$key]['max'])
    $max[$key] = array('index'=>$index,'max'=>$inner_arr[$key]);
}

print_r($max);
```

**EDIT: ABOVE CODE SHORTENED**

```
$max = array('pda'=>0,'prt'=>0,'kps'=>0);
array_walk($arr,'get_max');

function get_max($inner_arr,$index) {
    global $max;
    foreach (array_keys($max) as $key) {
        if ($inner_arr[$key] > $max[$key]['max'])
        $max[$key] = array('index'=>$index,'max'=>$inner_arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, and it helped me learn new ways of doing things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most elegant solution I can think of:

```
$max=Array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key=>$nestedArray) {
    foreach ($nestedArray as $item => $val) {
        if (!isset($max[$item]) || $max[$item]['val']<$val) {
            $max[$item]['val']=$val;
            $max[$item]['key']=$key;
        }
    }
}
```